# winston logger with webpack 5 in reactjs

Tags: winston, webpack-5

[Image related the err that i faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xexWO.jpg)when I implementing Winston logger in react application it is throwing error.
in React Application I already using Webpack version 5.

in the image that I shared. such type issue I am getting.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)